# Convolution of an Image with Gaussian sigma = 1

Tags: image-processing, probability-or-statistics, convolution

I'm new to image processing and I've been testing out different Gaussian blur filters.

Out of curiosity, I generated an object that is a 2D Gaussian with sigma = 1. [image]

I convolved this object with a Gaussian of sigma = 1, and while their individual pixel values are different they look very nearly the same. I then changed the sigma of my Object to 5 (in both x and y directions) and found that convolution with a Gaussian of sigma = 1 gave the same result. Is there something deep going on here, or is a Gaussian of sigma = 1 just very weak?

Comment: Please, add the image file as attachment. Did you tried to code?

Comment: I suggest that you try the same thing in one dimension first. Then you may see what's happening more clearly.

Comment: Basically, a Gaussian with sigma=5 convolved with a Gaussian with sigma=1 equals a Gaussian with sigma=`Sqrt[5^2 + 1^2] ~= 5.1`. So they should look similar. You can find a proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Proof_using_convolutions